# Deprecation of twig filters, use Twig_SimpleFilter instead

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony 2.3 and have deprecation warnings in my profiler related to Twig. Such as:

```
DEPRECATION - Using "replace" with character by character replacement is deprecated 
and will be removed in Twig 2.0
```

And the `|replace` tag seems to be still part of the Twig documentation, so I am a little confused on how to deal with this Warning.

Also, I get similar Deprecation Warnings from third-party bundles that I use.

- Is there an easy way to fix this?
- Is this going to be an issue if I upgrade from 2.3 to 2.7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the way you pass the **arguments** to replace function in twig :

- before : `{{str | replace ('a','b') }}`
- now : `{{str | replace ({'a': 'b'}) }}`

Before it was two arguments, now it's an array.

You can check in the code source that it's not the replace twig_replace_filter function wich is deprecated but only one way of calling it : https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/1.x/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php#L534

Note that the twig doc display the right example :
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the only way to fix it is to replace all your deprecated functions.

But this should cause troubles only if you upgrade your twig bundle by :

- Composer update if you have a tag in your `composer.json` which is not a version (like `"twig/extensions": "1.*",`)
- If you upgrade your symfony with a version which requires twig 2.x

In fact, you're project won't be affected by this warning if you stay on this version.

Comment: I have probably missed something in the doc ( http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html ) but they don't seem to mention any kind of deprecation or replacement. Does it mean that I have to instead code the filter by myself?

Comment: No you don't have to code. The link you gave me is for the 1.23 version.  Which support the `replace` filter. The doc is maintained by humans and maybe they forgot to put the `2.0` deprecation in it. If you want to pass on twig 2, the replace filter will be replaced by something else. But why do you want to upgrade your twig extension ?

Comment: I want to clean the deprecation warning before upgrading to Symfony 2.7. I could not find any substitute for the `replace` filter using Google which is why I asked if you, or anyone, knew of a good place to find the relevant information. If you tell me that this warning won't affect my upgrade process (ie. Symfony 2.7 does not require twig 2.x), then I'd be more than happy to begin the upgrading process.

Comment: Symfony 2.7 is using 1.23 at the moment. Which is the last stable version of twig. If you can't fin any substitute it's because that doesn't exist yet. This warning shouldn't be a problem to upgrade your project. But care, because an upgrade from 2.3 to 2.7 can cause you a lot of problems. But I'm sure you searched about all issues :)

Comment: This deprecation warning was part of that process ;) Thank you!